# Running virtual directories with a different .Net framework than the web site

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have a web site running .net 4.0 and need to run 2 virtual directories under the site that are .net 2.0.  I have them separated into their own app pools (main site = App Pool 1, 2 virtual directories = App Pool 2) and the asp.net tab is set properly on main site and the virtual directories.

I see this error when I try to hit the sites in my virtual directories.

Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
Exception message: Unrecognized attribute 'optimizeCompilations'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. (D:\\web.config line 92)

I'm running IIS 6.0, server 2003.  I know you can do it with multiple virtual directories but it doesn't seem to work the same with the main site being different than the virtual directories.

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue in the past when I am trying to run a higher version of the framework in the root and a older version in the VD.  In my case it was due to ASP.NET Web.config inheritance.  I was able to get around by following the details laid out in this post:

[Stopping ASP.NET Web.config Inheritance](http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/05/16/stopping-asp-net-web-config-inheritance)